# Compiling GDAL/OGR with MinGW on Windows

Tags: windows, mingw, qt-creator, gdal, msys

I've been trying to link the GDAL library to qt-creator this last week, but have been having problems compiling the library in order to correctly link it.
I am getting this error

```
libtool: link: g++ .libs/gdalinfo_bin.o -o .libs/gdalinfo.exe  -L/local64/lib /c/gdal-2.1.0/.libs/libgdal.a -lodbc32 -lodbccp32 -lz -lpthread -lws2_32
C:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libiconv.a(localcharset.o):localcharset.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `__imp_GetACP'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/gdal-2.1.0/apps'
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

After having so many problems with the compiler, I am unsure whether this is a problem with setup or whether I need to reconfigure something in the gdal library for windows/mingw consumption.

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT: This may causing the problem, although I am unsure how to fix it

```
*** Warning: linker path does not have real file for library -lz.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have
*** because I did check the linker path looking for a file starting
*** with libz and none of the candidates passed a file format test
*** using a file magic. Last file checked: C:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libz.a
*** The inter-library dependencies that have been dropped here will be
*** automatically added whenever a program is linked with this library
*** or is declared to -dlopen it.

*** Since this library must not contain undefined symbols,
*** because either the platform does not support them or
*** it was explicitly requested with -no-undefined,
*** libtool will only create a static version of it.
```

Previous attempt lead me to believe that I needed the MinGW-64 version which was not designated by the GDAL instructions, so I used [this](http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/local.html) tutorial to modify MinGW for 64 bit libraries

Comment: Could you try to link Kernel32.lib to theapplication? The missing symbol, which is in use by ::GetText( .. ), is defined there.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean. I am currently compiling the library from source, so there is not an application involved at this point

Comment: Ok, but somehow the symbol from a Kernel.lib was missing. My recommendation would be: try to link it and check if this fixes the unresolved symbol.

Comment: adding 'LIBS += -L"C:\Windows\System32" -lkernal32' to the make file did not fix the problem

Comment: I think so, the name of the lib is kernel32.lib, not kernal :-).

Comment: Ah, you are correct. That did not fix the problem unfortunately

Comment: Just checked your output in the post. Do you have some kind of a mixup of 64bit and 32bit libs for libz?

Comment: this may be the problem. I am having difficulty compiling libz for mingw64bit so I will notify if I can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved it by by:

- compiling `ZLib`,
- placing `zlib1.dll` in `MinGW/bin`,
- placing `libz.a` and `libz.dll.a` in `MinGW/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest moving your development toolset to use [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) and its package manager. It includes a ton of precompiled libraries, such as GDAL, so you don't have to spend time on trying to get those to compile.